# How do I show a view in SwiftUI from a button press when the view that needs to be shown has a CoreData parameter?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-data

I'm trying to create a SwiftUI app where you can add food items to a list and edit them using a button. Here is my current code:

ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjContext
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.date, order: .reverse)]) var food: FetchedResults<Food>
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                List {
                    ForEach(food) { food in
                        HStack {
                            Text(food.name!)
                                .bold()
                            Spacer()
                            Text(calcTimeSince(date: food.date!))
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            Spacer()
                            Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    // This is where I want to show my edit view
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .listStyle(.plain)
            }
            .navigationTitle("List App")
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

EditView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct EditFoodView: View {
    @Environment (\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var food: FetchedResults<Food>.Element
    
    @State private var name = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                TextField("\(food.name!)", text: $name)
                    .onAppear {
                        name = food.name!
                    }
                
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button("Save") {
                        DataController().editFood(food: food, name: name, context: managedObjContext)
                        dismiss()
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the past, I set it up as a navigation link in the ForEach loop:

```
ForEach(food) { food in
NavigationLink(destination: EditFoodView(food: food) {
}
```

This worked, but I wanted to make it so that clicking on the actual text element has a different functionality. When I tried adding a button for each item that will pull up the edit view using a NavigationLink, it still made it so that any click on the text element would bring the edit view. My goal is so that only the button will bring up the edit view, but clicking on the text will bring up a different view.

Comment: How do you want to "bring up" the edit view? IMHO, best suited for this would be a sheet where you can edit the detail content – not a detail view, which will be navigated to.

Comment: Yes, I think that is a good idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a an image in a navigationLink using a trailing closure.
Therefore you can add a navigationLink only your image `Image(systemName: "info.circle")`

With something like that :

```
HStack {
    Text(food.name!)
        .bold()
    Spacer()
    Text(calcTimeSince(date: food.date!))
        .foregroundColor(.gray)
    Spacer()
    NavigationLink(destination: EditFoodView(food: food)) {
        Image(systemName: "info.circle")
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
    }
}
```

[edit]
Here is the procedure to test it:

- Create a new project in Xcode with swiftUI
- replace the whole code ContentView by the following :

```
import CoreData
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let food = Food()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            HStack {
                Text(food.name!)
                    .bold()
                Spacer()
                Text(calcTimeSince(date: food.date!))
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                Spacer()
                NavigationLink(destination: EditFoodView(food: food)) {
                    Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                }
            }
            
        }.padding()
    }
    
    func calcTimeSince(date: String) -> String {
        "plop"
    }
}

struct EditFoodView: View {
    @Environment (\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var food: FetchedResults<Food>.Element
    
    @State private var name = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                TextField("\(food.name!)", text: $name)
                    .onAppear {
                        name = food.name!
                    }
                
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button("Save") {
                        DataController().editFood(food: food, name: name, context: managedObjContext)
                        dismiss()
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class DataController {
    
    func editFood(food: Food, name: String, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        // do something
    }
}

class Food:NSObject, NSFetchRequestResult {
    let date: String? = ""
    let name: String? = "name"
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Only the "i" icon is clickable and navigates to the edit section

Comment: I have tried this it makes the whole text a navlink

Comment: That's weird because it doesn't on my exemple project where "name" and "plop" are not clickable and only the "i" icon is.